# How to increase the character limit of 255 on column "comments"?

Tags: column, limitations

I am using sp2013. I have created a content type and using the OOTB column "comments". Default it looks like below and has a limit of 255 characters. How can I increase this limit to 1000 characters?

[image]

Comment: check this one http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37162/sharepoint-multiple-line-of-text-char-limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the Allow unlimited length checkbox on the list column's properties page.

In the above case please select **Ja** for `Onbeperkte lengte in document bibliotheken teostaan`

Comment: but this will be unlimited. How can I limit it to 1000 characters? Can I add some validator in my custom pagelayout?