# Maximum characters in Multiple lines of text Column

Tags: 2013

How many maximum characters in Multiple lines of text Column can be added in SharePoint 2013 ?

I am not able to find anything on here,

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#Column

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Document libraries and lists have different options available with respect to the multiple lines of text column type.

In document libraries, when you create a new column of type Multiple Lines of Text, you get the option to select the `Allow unlimited length in document libraries` checkbox.

But, In lists, this option does not exist.

A multi line text field is defined in SharePoint as a `Note` type, this is stored in the `DB` as a `ntext sql type`. In this SQL type you can store `2gb` of `char data`, that's `1,073,741,823` characters.

> Note: It is not advisable to store such huge data in SharePoint column
>   as it may hamper performance.

Explanation referred from [this TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5e8cc504-03d0-4d26-81f9-1608c2c5881f/what-is-the-max-limit-for-number-of-characters-in-multiline-text-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)

Also if your are working with multi lines text field in Doc libs then [this is a nice article to read](http://sharepointtaproom.com/2011/01/16/max-length-of-a-multi-line-text-note-field-on-sharepoint-publishing-page/)

I hope this is a helpful information!!

Comment: I've a question what constitutes a "line" in a multi-line text box. So, the "Number of Lines for Editing" defaulted at 6 but is that for every time a string of text is moved to the next "line” or is it when the user hits the enter key and starts a new "line". I've never gotten a clear answer on this and need to know for a form I'm creating. (Yes, I know this is not an answer, but I don't have comment privileges yet, please don't delete.)

Comment: @KylerHunter its a good question. I might not be able to answer in that detail. To get a better response I can advise you to post a new question, where ppl with respective knowledge can give you answers.

Answer (score 5):

> [A Multiple lines of text column can store up to 63,999 characters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/List-and-library-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: This pertains to lists; Doc libraries can hold 1 billion+ chars albeit with performance degradation

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score -3):

It has maximum limit of 255 characters. but if you want more limit You have to check the Allow unlimited length checkbox on the list column's properties page.

and if you want to limit it to 1000 characters or whatever you feel like . Please follow this link [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37162/sharepoint-multiple-line-of-text-char-limit) to get the complete solution

Comment: not for multiline column

Comment: 255 = single line of text type limit; not multi-line limit